# Get JSON result of ethereum stats with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Need your help. I have a json array:

```
ethereumStats = {"blockTime": 16.890625, "lastUpdate": 1497042002.725094, "priceUsd": 275.742, "difficulty": 663594472929704.8};
```

How can i get the result of each data from array.

i tried this way:

```
$info = file_get_contents("http://alpha61.com/ethereum.json"); 
$result = json_decode($info,true);

$blockTime = $result["priceUsd"];
```

But it does'n work.

Comment: The string that is being returned isnt `JSON`. You need to `json_decode` on only the text on the right side of the `=`, and without the `;`. Is that url yours?

Comment: no, this url i use to get result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something I threw together to parse out the JSON string from the file that is returned:

```
$info = file_get_contents("http://alpha61.com/ethereum.json"); 
$data = explode(" = ", $info);
$json = rtrim($data[1],";");
$result = json_decode($json,true)
$blockTime = $result["priceUsd"];
```

The file you are requesting was meant to be used in a javascript tag, like this `<script src="http://alpha61.com/ethereum.json"></script>`, so its a little awkward to pull the JSON out of it for use in php